# Elastic Search wildcard query not working with case insensitive ( for lower case)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to fetch records from elasticsearch using wildcard queries.

Please find the below query

```
get my_index12/_search
{ 
  "query": { 
  "wildcard": { 
  "code.keyword": { 
          "value": "*ARG*" 
        } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

It's working and giving expected results for the above query., but it is not working for the lower case value.

```
get my_index12/_search
{ 
  "query": { 
  "wildcard": { 
  "code.keyword": { 
          "value": "*Arg*" 
        } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following:

Mapping:

```
PUT my_index12
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
   }
  }
},
"mappings": {
"doc": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Then Run `Query String` Query

```
GET my_index12/_search
{
"query": {
"query_string": {
  "default_field": "code",
  "query": "AB\\-7000*"
    }
  }
}
```

It will also work for `ab-7000*`

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: its not working as per expected `GET my_index12/_search
{
"query": {
"query_string": {
  "default_field": "code",
  "query": "-7000*"
    }
  }
}` am getting this result for the search query `{
AB-7000-4200-Wk-21,
AB-7000-5000-Wk-21,
sG66tsdF
}`

Comment: Have updated my answer . Somehow `hyphen` in the beginning was behaving in a strange manner. Use Validate api to verify this `GET my_index12/_validate/query?explain
{"query":{"query_string":{"fields":["code"],"query":"-7000*"}}}` .

Comment: Am getting this error for this request `request [/my_index12/_validate/query] contains unrecognized parameter: [explain {] -> did you mean [explain]?`

Comment: I am able to run this query. I have `6.2.4` as ES version. But anyways, the query should work. Is it fulfilling all your use cases?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize your keyword field:

[ElasticSearch normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html)

Something like (from documentation):

```
PUT index
 {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
    "normalizer": {
       "my_normalizer": {
       "type": "custom",
       "char_filter": [],
       "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
     }
   }
 }
},
"mappings": {
  "_doc": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Some additional info:

> Only parts of the analysis chain that operate at the character level are applied. So for instance, if the analyzer performs both lowercasing and stemming, only the lowercasing will be applied: it would be wrong to perform stemming on a word that is missing some of its letters.
>
> By setting analyze_wildcard to true, queries that end with a * will be analyzed and a boolean query will be built out of the different tokens, by ensuring exact matches on the first N-1 tokens, and prefix match on the last token.

Comment: I have created this normalizer `{
  "my_index12": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "code": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}` and querying `get my_index12/_search
 { 
   "query": { 
   "wildcard": { 
   "code.keyword": { 
     "value": "*AB-7000-5000-Wk-21*" 
   } 
  } 
   } 
 }` and am not getting the results.